# Input text value not updating bean property

Tags: java, jsf-1.2

I know that there's a lot of related questions about it, but i don't know what is wrong here.

Here's my page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:s="http://jboss.com/products/seam/taglib"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich" template="../Principal.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="conteudoPrincipal">

        <div class="areacadastro">
            <h2 class="nomeTela">
                <h:outputText value="#{msg.negociacao_titulo_cadastrar_cliente}" />
            </h2>
        </div>

        <div class="contentResultado">

            <h:form id="cadastrarFinanceiroForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                <table class="table">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="tableInfClienteLeft">
                                <div class="title-menu-cliente">
                                    <h2>
                                        <h:outputText
                                            title="#{msg.negociacao_cadastro_cliente_titulo_menu}" for=""
                                            value="#{msg.negociacao_cadastro_cliente_titulo_menu}" />
                                    </h2>
                                </div>
                                <div class="resumeMenu">
                                    <ui:include src="ClienteMenuLateral.xhtml" />
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="tableInfClienteRight">
                                <!-- Inicio da Mensagem de erro  --> <a4j:outputPanel
                                    id="panelMsgErro">
                                    <div id="divMensagemErroNegociacao" style="margin-top: -6px;">
                                        <ui:include src="../BlocoMensagensDeErro.xhtml" />
                                    </div>
                                </a4j:outputPanel> <!-- Fim da Mensagem de erro  --> <ui:include
                                    src="PainelInformacoesCliente.xhtml" />

                                <fieldset class="fieldset-CadastrarNegociacao">
                                    <legend class="legend-CadastrarNegociacao-Cliente"
                                        id="imgSicDadosGerais-financeiro">
                                        <span class="setaBaixo" id="setaImgSicDadosGerais"><img
                                            id="imgSetaDadosGerais-financeiro"
                                            src="../../imagesFedex/arrowup_orange.png" /> <rich:jQuery
                                                selector="document"
                                                query="colapsarComImagem('#imgSicDadosGerais-financeiro',
                                                    '.visualizar-box-financeiro',
                                                    '#imgSetaDadosGerais-financeiro',
                                                    '../../imagesFedex/arrowup_orange.png',
                                                    '../../imagesFedex/arrowdown_orange.png')" />
                                        </span>
                                        <h:outputText
                                            value="#{msg.negociacao_cadastro_cliente_titulo_financeiro}" />
                                    </legend>
                                    <div
                                        class="fluxo-Campos-DadosAtivo fluxo-Box visualizar-box-financeiro">
                                        <div class="clearfix">
                                            <ul class="base-align-Campos" id="tabelaFinanceiro">
                                                <li class="linha-campos-dadosTabelas-second"><h5
                                                        class="textInformatImportant">
                                                        <span class="textoInformativo"><h:outputText
                                                                value="#{msg.campos_obrigatorios}" /></span>
                                                    </h5></li>
                                                <li class="linha-campos-dadosTabelas">
                                                    <div class="base-label-input">
                                                        <div class="label-align label-align-large">
                                                            <h:outputLabel
                                                                value="#{msg.financeiro_filial_resp_cobranca}"
                                                                for="filialCobranca" />
                                                            <span class="estilo-asterisco estilo-asterisco-add"><h:outputText
                                                                    value="#{msg.campoSimbolo}" /></span>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="input-align selectTabelas-regular">
                                                            <a4j:outputPanel id="cbFilialCobranca">
                                                                <h:selectOneMenu id="filialCobranca" tabindex="1"
                                                                    value="#{actionCadastrarFinanceiroCliente.descricaoUnidade}"
                                                                    label="#{msg.selecione}" required="false">
                                                                    <f:selectItems
                                                                        value="#{actionCadastrarFinanceiroCliente.filiaisOrigem}"></f:selectItems>
                                                                    <a4j:support ajaxSingle="true" event="onchange"
                                                                        action="#{actionCadastrarFinanceiroCliente.popularDescricaoCP}"
                                                                        reRender="condPagamento" />
                                                                </h:selectOneMenu>
                                                            </a4j:outputPanel>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="base-label-input">
                                                        <div class="label-align label-align-large">
                                                            <h:outputLabel value="#{msg.financeiro_cond_pagamento}"
                                                                for="condPagamento" />
                                                            <span class="estilo-asterisco estilo-asterisco-add"><h:outputText
                                                                    value="#{msg.campoSimbolo}" /></span>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="input-align select-align">
                                                            <a4j:outputPanel id="cbCondPagamento">
                                                                <h:selectOneMenu id="condPagamento" tabindex="2"
                                                                    value="#{actionCadastrarFinanceiroCliente.idCondicaoPagamento}"
                                                                    label="#{msg.selecione}" required="false">
                                                                    <f:selectItems
                                                                        value="#{actionCadastrarFinanceiroCliente.descricaoCP}"></f:selectItems>
                                                                </h:selectOneMenu>
                                                            </a4j:outputPanel>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </li>
                                                <li class="linha-campos-dadosTabelas">
                                                    <div class="base-label-input">
                                                        <div class="label-align dark-label label-align-large">
                                                            <h:outputLabel value="#{msg.financeiro_portador}"
                                                                for="portador" />
                                                            <span class="estilo-asterisco estilo-asterisco-add"><h:outputText
                                                                    value="#{msg.campoSimbolo}" /></span>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="input-align selectTabelas-regular">
                                                            <a4j:outputPanel id="cbPortador">
                                                                <h:selectOneMenu id="portador" tabindex="3"
                                                                    value="#{actionCadastrarFinanceiroCliente.financeiro.portador}"
                                                                    label="#{msg.selecione}" required="false">
                                                                    <f:selectItems
                                                                        value="#{actionCadastrarFinanceiroCliente.portador}"></f:selectItems>
                                                                </h:selectOneMenu>
                                                            </a4j:outputPanel>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="base-label-input">
                                                        <div class="label-align dark-label label-align-large">
                                                            <h:outputLabel value="#{msg.financeiro_val_max_fatura}"
                                                                for="limiteFatura" />
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="input-align input-align-regular">
                                                            <h:inputText id="limiteFatura" tabindex="4"
                                                                required="false" maxlength="20"
                                                                class="mascaraMiolo input-regular"
                                                                value="#{actionCadastrarFinanceiroCliente.financeiro.limiteMaximoFaturaTransient}"
                                                                size="20" label="#{msg.financeiro_val_max_fatura}">
                                                            </h:inputText>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </li>
                                                <li class="linha-campos-dadosTabelas">
                                                    <div class="base-label-input">
                                                        <div class="baseLabel_Input">
                                                            <div class="label-align label-align-large">
                                                                <h:outputLabel value="#{msg.financeiro_qtd_cte_fatura}"
                                                                    for="qtdCteFatura" />
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="input-align input-align-regular">
                                                                <h:inputText id="qtdCteFatura" tabindex="5"
                                                                    styleClass="maskNumber" required="false" maxlength="20"
                                                                    value="#{actionCadastrarFinanceiroCliente.financeiro.quantidadeCTEFaturaTransiente}"
                                                                    size="20" label="#{msg.financeiro_qtd_cte_fatura}">
                                                                </h:inputText>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="base-label-input">
                                                        <div class="label-align label-align-large">
                                                            <h:outputLabel value="#{msg.financeiro_pag_comprovante}"
                                                                for="cbCompPagamento" />
                                                            <span class="estilo-asterisco estilo-asterisco-add"><h:outputText
                                                                    value="#{msg.campoSimbolo}" /></span>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="input-align selectTabelas-regular">
                                                            <a4j:outputPanel id="cbCompPagamento">
                                                                <h:selectOneMenu id="compPagamento" tabindex="6"
                                                                    value="#{actionCadastrarFinanceiroCliente.financeiro.pagamentoComprovante}"
                                                                    label="#{msg.selecione}" required="false">
                                                                    <f:selectItems
                                                                        value="#{actionCadastrarFinanceiroCliente.atrasoPagamento}"></f:selectItems>
                                                                </h:selectOneMenu>
                                                            </a4j:outputPanel>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </li>
                                                <li class="linha-campos-dadosTabelas">
                                                    <div class="base-label-input">
                                                        <div class="label-align dark-label">
                                                            <h:outputLabel
                                                                value="#{msg.negociacao_cadastro_cliente_recebe_fatura_correio}"
                                                                for="recebeFaturaCorreio" />
                                                            <span class="estilo-asterisco estilo-asterisco-add"><h:outputText
                                                                    value="#{msg.campoSimbolo}" /></span>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="input-align selectTabelas-regular">
                                                            <a4j:outputPanel id="painelrecebeFaturaCorreio">
                                                                <h:selectOneMenu id="recebeFaturaCorreio" tabindex="10"
                                                                    value="#{actionCadastrarFinanceiroCliente.financeiro.flagRecebimentoFaturaPagamento}"
                                                                    label="#{msg.selecione}" required="false">
                                                                    <f:selectItems
                                                                        value="#{actionCadastrarFinanceiroCliente.recebeFaturaCorreio}"></f:selectItems>
                                                                    <a4j:support ajaxSingle="true" event="onchange"
                                                                        action="#{actionCadastrarFinanceiroCliente.preencherFlagRecebimentoFaturaPagamento}"
                                                                        reRender="conteudoPrincipal" />
                                                                </h:selectOneMenu>
                                                            </a4j:outputPanel>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </fieldset>
                                <fieldset class="fieldset-CadastrarNegociacao">
                                    <legend class="legend-CadastrarNegociacao-Cliente"
                                        id="imgSicDadosGerais-bloqueio">
                                        <span class="setaBaixo" id="setaImgSicDadosGerais"><img
                                            id="imgSetaDadosGerais-bloqueio"
                                            src="../../imagesFedex/arrowup_orange.png" /> <rich:jQuery
                                                selector="document"
                                                query="colapsarComImagem('#imgSicDadosGerais-bloqueio',
                                                    '.visualizar-box-bloqueio',
                                                    '#imgSetaDadosGerais-bloqueio',
                                                    '../../imagesFedex/arrowup_orange.png',
                                                    '../../imagesFedex/arrowdown_orange.png')" />
                                        </span>
                                        <h:outputText value="#{msg.bloq_finan_titulo}" />
                                    </legend>
                                    <div
                                        class="fluxo-Campos-DadosAtivo fluxo-Box visualizar-box-bloqueio">
                                        <div class="clearfix">
                                            <ul class="baseAlinhaCampos" id="tabelaFinanceiro">
                                                <li class="linha-campos-dadosTabelas-second"><h5
                                                        class="textInformatImportant">
                                                        <span class="textoInformativo"><h:outputText
                                                                value="#{msg.campos_obrigatorios}" /></span>
                                                    </h5></li>
                                                <li class="linha-campos-dadosTabelas">
                                                    <div class="base-label-input">
                                                        <div class="label-align label-align-large">
                                                            <h:outputLabel value="#{msg.bloq_finan_lim_credito}"
                                                                for="limiteCredito" />
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="input-align input-align-regular">
                                                            <h:inputText id="limiteCredito" tabindex="1"
                                                                required="false" maxlength="20" class="mascaraMiolo"
                                                                value="#{actionCadastrarFinanceiroCliente.financeiro.limiteCreditoTransient}"
                                                                size="20" label="Limite Credito">
                                                            </h:inputText>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="base-label-input">
                                                        <div class="label-align label-align-large">
                                                            <h:outputLabel value="#{msg.bloq_finan_atraso_pg}"
                                                                for="cbAtrasoPagamento" />
                                                            <span class="estilo-asterisco estilo-asterisco-add"><h:outputText
                                                                    value="#{msg.campoSimbolo}" /></span>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="input-align selectTabelas-regular">
                                                            <a4j:outputPanel id="cbAtrasoPagamento">
                                                                <h:selectOneMenu id="atrasoPagamento" tabindex="2"
                                                                    value="#{actionCadastrarFinanceiroCliente.financeiro.atrasoPagamento}"
                                                                    label="#{msg.selecione}" required="false">
                                                                    <f:selectItems
                                                                        value="#{actionCadastrarFinanceiroCliente.atrasoPagamento}"></f:selectItems>
                                                                </h:selectOneMenu>
                                                            </a4j:outputPanel>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </li>
                                                <li class="linha-campos-dadosTabelas">
                                                    <div class="base-label-input">
                                                        <div class="label-align dark-label label-align-large">
                                                            <h:outputLabel value="#{msg.bloq_finan_inativo}"
                                                                for="cbInativo" />
                                                            <span class="estilo-asterisco estilo-asterisco-add"><h:outputText
                                                                    value="#{msg.campoSimbolo}" /></span>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="input-align selectTabelas-regular">
                                                            <a4j:outputPanel id="cbInativo">
                                                                <h:selectOneMenu id="inativo" tabindex="3"
                                                                    value="#{actionCadastrarFinanceiroCliente.financeiro.inativo}"
                                                                    label="#{msg.selecione}" required="false">
                                                                    <f:selectItems
                                                                        value="#{actionCadastrarFinanceiroCliente.atrasoPagamento}"></f:selectItems>
                                                                </h:selectOneMenu>
                                                            </a4j:outputPanel>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </fieldset>
                                <div class="align-ButtonsCadastro">
                                    <a4j:region>
                                        <a4j:commandButton styleClass="cancelbutton"
                                            value="#{msg.cancelar}" tabindex="4"
                                            action="#{actionCadastrarDadosGeraisCliente.direcionarDadosGerais}"
                                            onclick="javascript:Richfaces.showModalPanel('progressWaitModalPanel');atualizarImagem();" />
                                        <a4j:commandButton styleClass="button" value="#{msg.salvar}"
                                            type="submit" tabindex="5"
                                            action="#{actionCadastrarFinanceiroCliente.incluirAlterarCliente}"
                                            onclick="javascript:Richfaces.showModalPanel('progressWaitModalPanel');atualizarImagem();">
                                            <s:defaultAction />
                                        </a4j:commandButton>
                                    </a4j:region>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </h:form>
        </div>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

My backing bean is session scoped, and all the getters and setters are there. But when i try to change the value of this inputtext for example:

```
<h:inputText id="limiteCredito" tabindex="1"
                                                                required="false" maxlength="20" class="mascaraMiolo"
                                                                value="#{actionCadastrarFinanceiroCliente.financeiro.limiteCreditoTransient}"
                                                                size="20" label="Limite Credito">
                                                            </h:inputText>
```

The value is always null. There are no errors as far as i know, only one form, etc etc...what could be the cause of it?

Comment: There's a little too much code in order to understand the problem correctly... What is the simplest way that you can reproduce your problem (how little code can you have where the problem persists)? Are the getters being called? Is the getFinanceiro() in your bean always returning a new instance of the Financeiro object for example? Are the `direcionarDadosGerais` or `incluirAlterarCliente` actually being called? More information is needed. Bean code would help as well

Comment: @MárioFernandes the methods are being called.  My set methods aren't. The getFinanceiro() returns a non-new object. I've tried to change the property for something like: value="#{actionCadastrarFinanceiroCliente.test}" (with the getters and setters, but when i checked it, its value was null.

Comment: Hard to understand, as I said, there's a little too much code, can you remove the `a4j:region` and see what happens?

Comment: @MárioFernandes The one surrounding the a4j:commandbuttons? If i do so, my methods won't be called

Comment: Strange, the whole View should be considered when removing, maybe the problem lies in the template then? I would advise you to simply try and create the simplest form possible (one input and one button) and see if everything is working.

Comment: @MárioFernandes I`ve done as you said and even created a new property for the inputtext but it didn`t work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71556/discussion-between-mario-fernandes-and-joao-victor).